# How can I delete all the char

Tags: string, matlab, char

```
Input ={'AABCDA';'AABDCA';'AACBDA';'AACDBA';'AADBCA';'AADCBA';'ABACDA';'ABADCA';'ABCADA';
'ABCDAA';'ABDACA';'ABDCAA';'ACABDA';'ACADBA';'ACBADA';'ACBDAA';'ACDABA';'ACDBAA';'ADABCA';'ADACBA';'ADBACA';'ADBCAA';'ADCABA';'ADCBAA'}
```

How can I delete all the char (`A`) and just keep only one char (`A`) at the beginning and one char (`A`) at the end in the `Input`? The expected output should be like this:

```
Input ={'ABCDA';'ABDCA';'ACBDA';'ACDBA';'ADBCA';'ADCBA';'ABCDA';'ABDCA';'ABCDA';
'ABCDA';'ABDCA';'ABDCA';'ACBDA';'ACDBA';'ACBDA';'ACBDA';'ACDBA';'ACDBA';'ADBCA';
'ADCBA';'ADBCA';'ADBCA';'ADCBA';'ADCBA'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply [`regexprep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html), using  a regular expression with [negative lookahead and lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
Output = regexprep(Input, '(?<!^)A(?!$)', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

replace(Inputs,'AA','A') would work if you only have to worry about pairs of A.

Comment: It isn't "replace" but "strrep" (strING repLACE)

Comment: replace has been around since 16b. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/replace.html

Comment: Sorry. I use an older release.

Comment: No worries! I would say replace has more sane vectorization behavior so it's worth using if you have it. With string, it's also faster than strrep on char.

Comment: From the OP's example, it is clear that the `A` to be removed is not always in a pair with another `A`, so I'm afraid this doesn't answer her question